# GMSGeocoder iOS SDK - Not receiving callback on reverse geocoding

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, reverse-geocoding

I am scrolling through each asset in an asset group and trying to retrieve locations from the existing data of the images used in Google Maps sdk 1.9.1. Here is the code that I wrote

```
-(NSString *) doRevGeoCodingForLocationWithLat:(double)lat AndLon:(double)lon {
__block NSString *finalAddress = nil;
GMSGeocoder *sharedInstance = [[GMSGeocoder alloc] init];
if (sharedInstance) {
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
    GMSReverseGeocodeCallback handler = ^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && response) {
            NSLog(@"Mil gaya");
            GMSAddress *firstAddress = [response firstResult];
            NSString *formattedAddress = nil;
            if (firstAddress.locality)
                formattedAddress = [NSString stringWithString:firstAddress.locality];

            if (firstAddress.administrativeArea) {
                if (formattedAddress)
                    formattedAddress = [formattedAddress stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@", firstAddress.administrativeArea];
                else
                    formattedAddress = [NSString stringWithString:firstAddress.administrativeArea];
            }
            if (firstAddress.country) {
                if (formattedAddress)
                    formattedAddress = [formattedAddress stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@", firstAddress.country];
                else
                    formattedAddress = [NSString stringWithString:firstAddress.country];
            }
            if (formattedAddress) {
                finalAddress = [NSString stringWithString:formattedAddress];
            }
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    };

    [sharedInstance reverseGeocodeCoordinate:coordinate completionHandler:handler];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
return finalAddress;
}
```

The problem is that the completionHandler callback is **never** called back from the SDK.
I have setup the google APIs console and the demo app bundled with the sdk is working perfectly.

I read from the documentation that the completionHandler is called on main queue of the app. Could the problem be happening because this operation is happening on a concurrent queue that is enumerating through the assets??
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you somehow destroy (release) the sharedInstance too early?

Comment: I am using ARC, so there is no manual code to destroy the sharedInstance

Comment: How is it defined then?

Comment: It is right there in the code. I know it is not right to declare the variable as sharedInstance and have corrected it now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ups my Bad. Anyway Try to make it global (as a test). Arc is releasing it right away right now and no asynchronous stuff succeeds

Answer (score 1):

Arc is releasing your loyal Geocoder variable right away right now and no asynchronous calls can proceed.

As a test/ hack make the sharedInstance global so it is kept around.